# Hardware to Support ROS, OpenCV, and Motor Control

Tags: ros, opencv, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to build a robot arm that has sonar and camera sensors to manipulate physical objects.  I intend to use ROS for the motion planning and sensor processing and OpenCV for the camera processing.  I'm early into this project and I've tentatively picked some hardware that I think will get me in the ballpark but I'm not really sure if it will work.

My choices so far are:  1) Pandaboard ES (dual-core ARM 1.6MHz) to run Lubuntu and ROS (motion planning, sensor processing) and OpenCV for video processing, 2) a Mini Maestro 16-channel PWM motor control driver to drive up to 10 motors (with room to grow), and 3) Talon SR H-bridge controllers for each of the motors.  Note that the motors are 12V and may have max currents up to 60A.  I assume that I'll be able to run the motor encoders back to the GPIO pins of the Pandaboard to form a closed-loop control system.

I'm worried that the Pandaboard won't have enough CPU power to handle all the image processing, motion control, and motor control.  Is there a better way to handle these needs?  Perhaps a different dedicated board to handle complete PID control of the motors? If so, what specifically would you suggest?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109486/hardware-to-support-ros,-opencv,-and-motor-control/) by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look into the [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) package. It works great with arduino for motor control using the polulo gear motors and encoders.
The [pi_robot](http://wiki.ros.org/pi-robot-ros-pkg) is another place to look for answers for using ros with arduino.

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1